# How to set different numbers of columns per row with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, gridlayoutmanager

I have virtual keyboard using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager with default spanSize of 11 columns per row.

There are different modes for both English and Russian keyboards, but when I click to change to English keyboard view I need to have keyboard set to 9 columns per row instead of 11, as it is for Russian Keyboard.

How to set different column numbers programmatically?

Comment: Thanks, but that one doesn't work on my code. In my case getSpanSize returns button width size (like 4 for space or 2 for shift).  But I need number of buttons in one row to be 9 or 11 depends on keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you update the keyboard layout, write this:

```
RecyclerView recycler =
    (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_keyboard_recycler_alpha);

recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager([context], [num columns]);
```

Every time you call `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager()`, it will simply replace the old layout manager. You can easily swap between 11 columns and 9 columns just by setting a new layout manager.